# How to update values for value slider from a geoJSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, slider, geojson

When a user selects a cultivar, values for the slider don't change on the web page. How do I solve this?
First, colored grids should change depending on the selected cultivar.
Secondly, the slider should update on the vales from the selected cultivar.
Finally, colored grids should change depending on the selected values.
Example: show all grids where value = 0 for the cultivar "B".

[image]

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Select box with id "cultivarSelect" -->
   <select id="cultivarSelect"></select>

   <!-- Value Slider -->
   <label for="valueSlider">Select Value:</label>
   <input type="range" id="valueSlider" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
   <output id="sliderOutput">0</output>
</div>
```

```
    // Load JSON data from the file
    fetch("gis_layers/2021_cc_monster_trial_cc_rgb_grid_maturity_trial.geojson")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonData => {
        // Extracting unique cultivar values
        const cultivars = [...new Set(jsonData.features.map(feature => feature.properties.cultivar))];
        const sliders = [...new Set(jsonData.features.map(feature => feature.properties.CC210408))];

        // Now, 'cultivars' and 'sliders' contains an array of unique cultivar values

        // Populating HTML select box
        const selectBox = document.getElementById("cultivarSelect");

        // Clear existing options
        selectBox.innerHTML = "";

        // Creating options and appending them to the select box
        cultivars.forEach(cultivar => {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = cultivar;
            option.text = cultivar;
            selectBox.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Add an event listener to the select box
        selectBox.addEventListener("change", function () {
            const selectedCultivar = this.value;

            // Update the style of the cc_210408_grid layer based on the selected cultivar
            cc_210408_grid.setStyle(function (feature) {
                const fillColor = feature.properties.cultivar === selectedCultivar ? get_cc_Color_210408_grid(feature.properties.CC210408) : 'black';

                return {
                    "color": 'black',
                    "weight": 1,
                    "opacity": 1,
                    "fillColor": fillColor,
                    "fillOpacity": 0.7
                };
            });
        });
        
        // Populating HTML slider
        const sliderBox = document.getElementById("valueSlider");

        // Clear existing options
        sliderBox.innerHTML = "";

        // Creating options and appending them to the select box
        sliders.forEach(CC210408 => {
            const option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = CC210408;
            option.text = CC210408;
            sliderBox.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Add an event listener to the slider
        document.getElementById("valueSlider").addEventListener("input", function () {
          const selectedValue = this.value;

          // Update the style of the cc_210408_grid layer based on the selected cultivar
          cc_210408_grid.setStyle(function (feature) {
              const fillColor = feature.properties.cultivar === selectedValue ? get_cc_Color_210408_grid(feature.properties.CC210408) : 'black';

              return {
                  "color": 'black',
                  "weight": 1,
                  "opacity": 1,
                  "fillColor": fillColor,
                  "fillOpacity": 0.7
              };
          });
      });


      })
      .catch(error => console.error("Error loading JSON data:", error));
```

geojsonFile

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "2021_cc_monster_trial_cc_rgb_grid_maturity_trial",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "plot_num": "B", "cultivar": "B", "CC210408": 0, "CC210412": 0.0, "CC210420": 0.0, "CC210429": 0.59095580678314497, "CC210506": 0.48118512110726602, "CC210514": 3.0538857878917991, "CC210520": 9.2636324602833824, "CC210524": 12.147690340455005, "CC210602": 26.634343864883586, "CC210609": 49.789546592785975, "CC210614": 52.951443986036182, "CC210623": 62.360848561226632, "CC210629": 69.087376601554297, "CC210708": 83.947700063011979, "CC210712": 83.745900772241626, "CC210720": 80.921482822795639, "CC210728": 87.28733459357278, "CC210810": 64.327422145328711, "CC210817": 3.2399979297137831, "line": "1", "rep": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -97.561380272876121, 27.783363698809357 ], [ -97.561370632411681, 27.78336368822972 ], [ -97.561370644307516, 27.783355114160909 ], [ -97.561380284771175, 27.783355124740513 ], [ -97.561380272876121, 27.783363698809357 ] ] ] ] } },
```